# is there any ORA message that table is deprecated?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm looking for a way to inform that oracle table should not be used any more.
It still in use, hence I can not use the mark as UNUSED for the table columns, as it throws an exception, but only for letting the developer know that from now on he shouldn't use it.

Comment: I'd think the developer -- in his role as the _developer_  -- would already know that the table is not to be used, and would have been involved in removing the table from the test system, and subsequently the production system.

Answer (score 3):

Create a comment?

```
comment on table emp is '30.12.2021, shagby: do not use that table any more';
```

---

Or, create a trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_test
  2    before insert or update or delete on test
  3  begin
  4    raise_application_error(-20000, '30.12.2021, shagby: do not use that table any more');
  5  end;
  6  /

Trigger created.

SQL> delete from test;
delete from test
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: 30.12.2021, shagby: do not use that table any more
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_TEST", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_TEST'


SQL> insert into test (col) values ('x');
insert into test (col) values ('x')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: 30.12.2021, shagby: do not use that table any more
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_TEST", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_TEST'


SQL> update test set col = 'y';
update test set col = 'y'
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: 30.12.2021, shagby: do not use that table any more
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_TEST", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_TEST'


SQL>
```

Comment: good solution!  I was going to suggest the non-technical solution of " for letting the developer know that from now on he shouldn't use it." would be to send the developer an email informing him of such!  :-)

Comment: This (what I suggested) isn't perfect either, @Eds. If all developers work in the same schema, they can drop the trigger or delete the comment. Therefore, I guess that sending them an e-mail wouldn't hurt :) Besides, you'd have an *evidence* that they were informed!

Comment: There is a "DEPRECATE" feature, but it only applies to some PL/SQL objects. I tried deprecating the trigger, hoping that dependent objects would then throw an error, but apparently triggers can't be deprecated. When I added `DECLARE PRAGMA DEPRECATE(TRG_TEST, 'The underlying table is deprecated.');` the package itself threw a warning `PLW-06022: cannot use PRAGMA DEPRECATE on this entity`.